# Using variables on select query table name

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

i need to use dynamic table names on model select query like this:

```
$this->db->select("$this->table_car.id as carId, $this->table_car.price as carPrice, $this->table_car.name as carName, $this->table_car.used as carUsed, $this->table_car.visible as carVisible, $this->table_cat.name as catName, $this->table_brand.name as carBrand, $this->table_model.name as carModel");
```

But variable is not working. This is what I get:

```
SELECT .`id` AS `carId`, .`price` AS `carPrice`, .`name` AS `carName`, .`used` AS `carUsed`, .`visible` AS `carVisible`, .`name` AS `catName`, .`name` AS `carBrand`, .`name` AS `carModel`
LEFT JOIN ON .`car_id` = .`id`
LEFT JOIN ON .`id` = .`cat_id`
LEFT JOIN ON .`id` = .`brand_model_id`
LEFT JOIN ON .`id` = .`model_id`
LEFT JOIN ON .`id` = .`brand_id`
WHERE .`used`= 0 LIMIT 3
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: make alias and use that alias

Comment: in "", you can use either $var or $var[something] so it would change it to value

Comment: Can u give me an example?

Comment: Ok. So the problem is using $this->table_name instead of $table_name? I tried  $table_name and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst double quotes do allow the use of variables inside them without the need to close and concatenate, it doesn't always work for the likes or object and arrays, like you are showing.  A better solution would be:

```
$this->db->select($this->table_car . ".id as carId, " 
    . $this->table_car . ".price as carPrice, " 
    . $this->table_car . ".name as carName, " 
    . $this->table_car . ".used as carUsed, " 
    . $this->table_car . ".visible as carVisible, " 
    . $this->table_cat . ".name as catName, " 
    . $this->table_brand . ".name as carBrand, " 
    . $this->table_model . ".name as carModel");
```

Another option would be to put your object variables in braces {} such as :

```
$this->db->select("{$this->table_car}.id as carId, 
    {$this->table_car}.price as carPrice, 
    {$this->table_car}.name as carName, 
    {$this->table_car}.used as carUsed, 
    {$this->table_car}.visible as carVisible, 
    {$this->table_cat}.name as catName, 
    {$this->table_brand}.name as carBrand, 
    {$this->table_model}.name as carModel");
```

Comment: Does your object have a variable called `$table_car`, `$table_brand` and `$table_name`?

Comment: I have a config with $config['tables'] = array('car' => 'car',);
Then on my model i call config item and assign to a object
$this->tables = $this->config->item('tables');
$this->table_car = $this->tables['car'];

Comment: @JonnyDevv it sounds like the variable `$this->table_car` and similar don't have any values.  Are you able to show us the contents of the model where this is being set?